# How to find the interior of this set?

Tags: metric-spaces

let $S=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb R):tr(A)=0\}$

The question is to check whether $S$ is Nowhere dense .I think the set is closed and hence the problem reduces to findind int(S).How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel $N$ of every non-trivial linear functional $f :V \to \Bbb{R}$ has empty interior (where $V$ is a normed vector space).

To see this, one possibility is to use that proper subspace of a normed vector space always has empty interior (try to show the contrapositive).

A direct proof is the following: There is $x\in V $ with $f(x)\neq 0$ (by assumption on $f$). For $y \in N$, this yields $f(y+ x/n)= f(x)/n \neq 0$ for every $n$. Why does that prove the claim?